# Prove that Two Re-encryptions of the Same ElGamal Pair have the Same Decryptions

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, elgamal-encryption

I'm working on an internet election system that requires the shuffling of ballots accompanied by an interactive proof of the legitimacy of the shuffle. I am working on [this paper](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/simple-verifiable-elections/) and I am stuck at the part outlined below:

By releasing the single value $(r'-r'')\mod(p-1)$, the two ElGamal pairs $(x',y')$ and $(x'',y'')$ can be shown to have the same decryptions without any linkage or association to the original ElGamal pair $(x,y)$.

I managed to get the value $(r'-r'')\mod(p-1)$ outlined above but I am not sure how to use this value to prove that both re-encryptions have the same decryption.

Thank you for the time ,

Andrei.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing in additive notation, suppose that we have a generator $G$ and public key $A$. Our two pairs are $(x’,y’)=(M+r’A,r’G)$ and $(x’’,y’’)=(M+r’’A,r’’G)$. Given $r’-r’’$, we can check that $y’-y’’=(r’-r’’)G$ and $x’-x’’=(r’-r’’)A$

In multiplicative notation we have $(x’,y’)=(MA^{r’},G^{r’})$ etc., we check that $y’/y’’=G^{r’-r’’}$ and $x’/x”=A^{r’-r’’}$.

Had the messages been different but with the same ephemeral $r$ values, the first check would pass, but not the second.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response and sorry for the delay on my side. I looked over the formulae provided and they seem to work given (x′,y′)=(M+r′A,r′G). In my case though, (x′,y′)=(MA^r', G^r'). Would you know how to adjust the proof to fit this?

Comment: Yes, this is multiplicative notation as in the second paragraph. I’ve edited to make this clearer.

Comment: Thanks for that, sorry to keep bothering, I tried implementing it through code (javascript, using jsbn library to do math on big integers) but I just can't seem to get it to work. I am trying to work out the left and right side of the equation and then equating them as below: 

`const left = y1.divide(y2);`
`const right = g.pow(proof);`
`console.log(left.equals(right));`

y1 is y', y2 is y'', and proof is (r'-r''). Whenever I raise g to the power of (r'-r''), I get 1 and when I divide y' by y'', I get a 0 is y1<y2 or a 1 if y1>y2. Would you know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: It sounds like you are doing naive arithmetic rather than arithmetic modulo $p$. You should have `left=(y1*modInverse(y2,p))%p` for a suitable modInverse function (I don't know what javascript has built in) and `right=modPower(g,proof,p)` for a suitable modPower function.

Comment: That was the issue! Thank you. I am facing one problem with it though. I am generating (r' - r'') as r' - r'' % p. The proof works provided r'>r'', but doesn't otherwise unless I change left=(y1*modInverse(y2, p))%p to left=(y2*modInverse(y1, p))%p. Would there be a way to resolve that mathematically so that I can get r'-r'' to work regardless of the inequality?

Comment: Yes. Instead use `(r'-r'')%(p-1)`

Comment: Yes that's it. Thanks so much for all the help. 